# Play Framework Join Table

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, playframework, entities

What I'm trying to do is to join a table to another table based on a user id.

I have a user table, and an alerts history table that has a foreign key associated with the user's ID.

I am using entities generated by Netbeans 7.4.

User:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Users", schema = "dbo")
public class User extends Model implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "UserID")
    private Integer userID;
            @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "userId")
            private Collection<AlertHistory> alertHistoryCollection;
     { ... }
```

Alert History:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Alert_History", schema = "dbo")
public class AlertHistory extends Model implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private int userId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "message_id")
    private long messageId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "alerts_triggered")
    private String alertsTriggered;
            {...}
```

What I would expect is that when I load a user, it will attempt to join the `AlertsHistory` table results based on the userId. However, at runtime, the `AlertsHistory` Collection is always `null`

**Update: SOLVED**

I was looking at this the wrong way. In order to do a JOIN, AlertHistory was expecting to be handed a User object, and not just the userId key. Adding a `User` field to the `AlertHistory` model, and changing the `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")` to `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user"`, then adding `@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="userId")
    private User user;` to that `User` field in `AlertHistory` got me sorted out! Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Shouldn't the atributte "private int userId" at AlertHistory be "private User userId" ?

Comment: Thanks @edubriguenti, that was the nail in the coffin! I was looking at this all wrong. I was thinking that I needed to pass the key (userId) when really I needed to simply reference the whole object. That got me into another problem because of what JPA was inferring as the column to match on (ie. it was looking for a column called user_userId which of course doesn't exist).

The solution there was to add the following to `AlertHistory`:
`@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="userId")
    private User user;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, nobody wants `null` collections, so do this in `User`:

```
private Collection<AlertHistory> alertHistoryCollection = new ArrayList<>();
//assuming Java 7
```

Then you need the `User` instance in `AlertHistory` like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "UserID")
private User user;
```

Comment: Thank you Vidya! This has seemingly gotten me a little closer. I also changed the collection type from `Collection` to `List`. I am now seeing more meaningful (read: any) compile time errors from Play:

     `PersistenceException: Error on models.User.alertHistoryCollection. mappedBy property [userId]is not a ManyToOne?in [models.AlertHistory]`

I have ensured that there is a `@ManyToOne` annotation on the userId field in the `AlertHistory` class.

Comment: First of all, `AlertHistory` is not supposed to have a `userId` field as I stated in my original answer. It has a `User` instance. However, I originally neglected to provide the `@JoinColumn` attribute, which I think you need as well. Edit made.